# load admob ad in activity and use it in different fragment for reducing the time to load the ad

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I have an activity in which I replace fragment on clicking one of the button which is placed in fragment.
While clicking on  the fragment it replaces the current fragment with another fragment.

My Question is, do I need to call the  code below  again and again for each fragment  within the same activity or can I place the code in activity and show the ad in fragments

```
    mAdView = (AdView)v.findViewById(R.id.beautyfragment);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

so for each fragment transaction do I need to put an ad request or only I can make request once in activity holding the fragments and display the ad in whichever fragment I want.

I had placed **admob banner ad** at the top and bottom of the each fragment to be  displayed on clicking.

I have some questions regarding it->

1. Can I make the ad load in activity and display it in fragment so it does not take time to be displayed in fragments placed within the same activity while transiting between the fragments. If yes please tell me the code for it.
2. Does it makes any difference using **Different adUnitId** for the **banner ads** shown on the screen,within the same fragment or different fragment within the **same activity** ?

Comment: yes you can place ad in activity

Comment: @Vishal please have a look at the question completely.

Comment: there is a time for receiving the ad and a time to refresh the ad. The receiving time depends on how fast the internet is. Each layout loads it's own ad. You can create an offline ad if you realy want and display it whenever you want

Comment: @Jules ,this is not,what i am asking

Comment: @Jules i need to know a way for loading the ad in activity,and displaying it within the fragments ,while i make a fragment transaction  within the same activity.

Comment: please rephrase the first question, in what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: so practicality you always want to display the ad, no matter the current fragment/transition etc

Comment: yes i need to display the ad,but the ad is placed inside the fragment layout.now my question is that whenever i make a fragment transaction the ad loads ,which takes 3-4 sec.i am trying to find a way so that the ad gets displayed as soon as the fragment opens.

Answer (score 0):

You have control over whether the AdView is located. According to your state requirements you could put the AdView

1. Directly into your Activity, below the Fragment that you are swapping in and out.
2. Into a Fragment (which is placed below the Fragment that you are swapping in and out).

The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You want to load ad in your main activity and show it in fragment quickly as fragment load. 
1- You shoud load ad in activity's onCreate method once and set AdListener too.
2- In AdListener, you can load ad again when user close the ad in onAdClosed method.
3- You need to show ad when commiting a fragment transaction. (which Ad is already loaded in activity's onCreate method)
4. User will close ad and ad will be loaded again in background in onAdClosed method so it will show again when user switch to another fragment.

Here is code to put in your main activity's onCreate method.

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("your ad unit id");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("your test device id")
            .build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.e("TAG", "Ad loaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Log.i("TAG", "Ad closed");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("your test device id")
                    .build());
        }
    });
```

And here is the code to put with fragment transaction.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.commit();

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
```